# VSTO Add-in Installer - Ask for some user information

Tags: vsto

I am developing EXCEL VSTO add-in where each user have their own license file to communicate with API. I am new to VSTO add-in development and have no experience on creating installer of VSTO Add-in. Is there any chance that in installer we can provide step where we ask user to upload license file before installation?

Answer (score 0):

There are two main ways for deploying Office solutions:

- [Deploy an Office solution by using Windows Installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/deploying-an-office-solution-by-using-windows-installer)
- [Deploy an Office solution by using ClickOnce](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/deploying-an-office-solution-by-using-clickonce)

All the required steps are described in the articles mentioned. It is up to you which one is to choose.

However, MSI (Windows Installer) allows to create a custom UI with custom actions that will work for you best.